# Team Foundation Server 2010 - build configuration not set for project

Tags: msbuild

(I´ve updated the title, to reflect my new findings)

I've just ported a bunch of projects from TFS2008 to TFS2010 and have run into a (actually several :)) problem with a specific project. When compiling with build configuration 'Debug', everything works as expected. However when compiling with build configuration 'Release' I get a linker error, due to al.exe cannot find the specified file in 'obj\debug'.

Error:

```
Task "AL" (TaskId:781)
...
ALINK : error AL1047: Error importing file 'c:\Builds\23\...\obj\Debug\someproject.exe' -- The system cannot find the file specified. [C:\Builds\23\...\Release\Sources\...\someproject.csproj]
  The command exited with code 1. (TaskId:781)
Done executing task "AL" -- FAILED. (TaskId:781)
```

I've enabled the team build info diagnostic logging and found the following variable:

```
IntermediateOutputPath = obj\Debug\
```

My question is why would the linker look in the Debug folder, when I'm building under the release configuration. I've inspected the solution and project configuration and there are no 'Debug' configurations under the release solution configuration. Any ideas why this is happening and how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

!! Bonus info

I have the following statement in the project file that is failing, assuring if the build configuration is unspecified, it will be set to Debug.

```
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
```

I've tried to change it to Release as default and now my debug team build fails, pointing at obj\release instead. So it seems that the build configuration is unspecified, when the project is compiled. How can this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. I have to set the build configuration explicitly for my publish target defined in the someproject.csproj project file. I've inserted the line 'Configuration=Release'

```
    <MSBuild ToolsVersion="3.5" Projects="$(SolutionRoot)\...someproject.csproj"
             Properties="RunCodeAnalysis=false;
                             Configuration=Release;
                             ClrVersion=2.0.50727.0;
             ApplicationVersion=$(VersionNumber);
             UpdateUrl=$(DevtestUpdateUrl);
             InstallUrl=$(DevtestInstallUrl);
             IsWebBootstrapper=true;
             PublishDir=$(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\Publish\Update\;
             SolutionDir=$(SolutionRoot)\Kl******\;
             DeploymentConfiguration=devtest;
             SignManifests=true;
                        ManifestCertificateThumbprint=23...23;"
             Targets="PublishOnly" />
```